# Wordpress' get_comments() only returns text and no HTML

Tags: php, wordpress, comments, wordpress-theming

I am using `get_comments()` to retrieve the comments of a specific wordpress post in my custom theme. The problem is that there is no HTML inside of the output.

for example when a user adds an URL to a comment, in the admin console it shows as a link but using `get_comments()` it returns just text.

As there are no filters or other options that covers this on this page: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments I don't quite know what is wrong. Am I supposed to manage that with javascript afterwards?

Thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess you could apply the 'the_content' filter;

```
<?php foreach (get_comments() as $comment): ?>
    <div class="comment">
        <?=apply_filters('the_content', $comment->comment_content) ?>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: It does add <p>'s but no links. :-/. Good idea though!

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend taking a look at an existing theme's `comments.php` template file, modifying it to suit your purposes, and then calling it via `comments_template()`.

The theme based on ZURB's Foundation Framework, [for example](https://github.com/drewsymo/Foundation/blob/master/comments.php) uses `wp_list_comments`:

```
<ol class="commentlist">
    <?php wp_list_comments(); ?>
</ol>
```

See if that gives you a more formatted output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this and it'll display the username, date, avatar and all its p tags.

```
      <div class="comments">
        <?php $comments_args = array(
        // change the title of send button 
        'label_submit'=>'Send',
        // change the title of the reply section
        'title_reply'=>'Write a new comment',
        // remove "Text or HTML to be displayed after the set of comment fields"
        'comment_notes_after' => '',
        // redefine your own textarea (the comment body)
        'comment_field' => '<p class="comment-form-comment"><textarea id="comment" name="comment" aria-required="true" placeholder="Type your comment"></textarea></p>',
        );

        comment_form($comments_args); ?>
      </div>
      <div class="comments-form">
        <?php

        $user_id = get_current_user_id();
        $user_specific_comments = get_comments(
            array(
                'post_id' => YOUR_POST_ID,
            )
        );

        wp_list_comments(
            array(
                'per_page' => 10,
            ),

            $user_specific_comments
        );
        ?>
      </div>
```